# Sound always comes from Apple Thunderbolt Display even with headphones connected

Tags: audio, display, thunderbolt, thunderbolt-display, windows

I have an issue using the Apple Thunderbolt Display. I have a Dell XPS laptop with Windows 8 where I connect to the display over Thunderbolt, but every time I try to listen to some music or video, the sound comes from the screen, not from my laptop, even if I plug headphones into the laptop. How can I solve this problem? I want to work using my laptop and the screen but I want to redirect the sound to my headphones. Is this possible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**In Windows**, you can typically choose a different output-source using this approach:

> For switching outputs, try this:
>   Right click on the speaker icon in the tray. Choose "playback
>   devices". Select from the list of playback devices (speakers, hdmi,
>   usb headset,) (the device you want) Choose "Set Default" Your audio
>   output will instantly switch <sub><sup>[Source](https://superuser.com/a/106788/136933)</sup></sub>

For quick access to this, you can download [this application](http://heilnizar.deviantart.com/art/PlaybackDevice-Audio-Output-Switch-285591834).

**Applicable to OS X users**:
You should be able to see the earphones in the music menu. Hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking the Audio-icon in the menubar. There you can switch between the different audio devices, like the external screen and the earphones.

This can also be done from System Prefrences -> Sound and the tab Output.

Comment: It's impossible I am using Windows 8

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll see if I can find a solution that works there as well.

Comment: On OS X, you can also hold Alt and tap one of the three volume buttons on the keyboard. It'll open Sound Preferences.

Answer (score 14):

For those seeing this in OS X instead of Windows, there is a separate sound output selection box for "Sound Effects". Make sure to select Headphones.

[image]

Comment: Argh, how obscure is that! This was it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

FYI I had a very similar problem. It was happening on Skype calls even when I had all the audio settings set to headphones. However, I then discovered that Skype has it's own preferences, and they were over-riding the computer settings and choosing the display audio.

I changed the Skype settings to "built-in" input and output (which seems counterintuitive because actually it was going to and from my earphones which I had plugged into the laptop!) Anyway, that fixed it and now I can make Skype calls using my earphone with mic!

Comment: Had the same issue with Zoom, they've got their own audio input/output settings (under the arrow on the mic button).